# git pull results in fatal error: runtime: out of memory

Tags: git, macos

This issue has occured recently and does not affect all repositories on my local machine.

When I try to `pull` this is the error I get:

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xa0fe1a, 0x16)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x72 fp=0x7ffde95e02a0 sp=0x7ffde95e0270 pc=0x42d812
runtime.sysMap(0xc000000000, 0x4000000, 0xf5d278)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:170 +0xc7 fp=0x7ffde95e02e0 sp=0x7ffde95e02a0 pc=0x4192a7
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0xf44ca0, 0x2000, 0xf44cb0, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:633 +0x1cd fp=0x7ffde95e0388 sp=0x7ffde95e02e0 pc=0x40c3ad
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0xf44ca0, 0x1, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1222 +0x42 fp=0x7ffde95e03e0 sp=0x7ffde95e0388 pc=0x4265c2
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0xf44ca0, 0x1, 0xf5d288, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1150 +0x37f fp=0x7ffde95e0418 sp=0x7ffde95e03e0 pc=0x4264af
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0xf44ca0, 0x1, 0x2a, 0x6e43a318)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:977 +0xc2 fp=0x7ffde95e0468 sp=0x7ffde95e0418 pc=0x425b02
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1048 +0x4c fp=0x7ffde95e04a0 sp=0x7ffde95e0468 pc=0x4554ec
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0xf44ca0, 0x1, 0x1002a, 0x7ffde95e0540)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1047 +0x8a fp=0x7ffde95e04f0 sp=0x7ffde95e04a0 pc=0x425dda
runtime.(*mcentral).grow(0xf45aa0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:256 +0x95 fp=0x7ffde95e0538 sp=0x7ffde95e04f0 pc=0x418d25
runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0xf45aa0, 0x7f1499cb9000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:106 +0x2ff fp=0x7ffde95e0598 sp=0x7ffde95e0538 pc=0x41882f
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x7f1499cb9008, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:135 +0x86 fp=0x7ffde95e05b8 sp=0x7ffde95e0598 pc=0x4182c6
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x7f1499cb9008, 0xf3b42a, 0x7f1499cb9008, 0x7f1499cb9000, 0x8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:786 +0x88 fp=0x7ffde95e05f0 sp=0x7ffde95e05b8 pc=0x40cbe8
runtime.mallocgc(0x180, 0xa02680, 0x1, 0xf5d2e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:939 +0x76e fp=0x7ffde95e0690 sp=0x7ffde95e05f0 pc=0x40d4fe
runtime.newobject(0xa02680, 0x4000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1068 +0x38 fp=0x7ffde95e06c0 sp=0x7ffde95e0690 pc=0x40d908
runtime.malg(0x538b8800008000, 0xf47310)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:3220 +0x31 fp=0x7ffde95e0700 sp=0x7ffde95e06c0 pc=0x436b81
runtime.mpreinit(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:311
runtime.mcommoninit(0xf3f760)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:618 +0xc2 fp=0x7ffde95e0738 sp=0x7ffde95e0700 pc=0x4305b2
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:540 +0x74 fp=0x7ffde95e0790 sp=0x7ffde95e0738 pc=0x430244
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ffde95e07c8, 0x2, 0x7ffde95e07c8, 0x0, 0x7f1499ade0ca, 0x2, 0x7ffde95e1dae, 0x7ffde95e1de9, 0x0, 0x7ffde95e1def, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:195 +0x11a fp=0x7ffde95e0798 sp=0x7ffde95e0790 pc=0x4572aa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have run `ssh-add` and restarted multiple times but to no avail.

OS: macOS Mojave (v: 10.14.6)

Comment: The stack trace is from the Go runtime. Git isn't written in Go. (Git-LFS, which is not Git, *is* written in Go; are you using Git-LFS?)

Comment: @torek I dont think I am - is there a way to check if Im using it?

Comment: You'd probably know if you had set it up, I think, as you'd have to have run `git lfs clone` or `git-lfs clone` initially.

Comment: In that case no - I have not used git lfs

Comment: OK, then this is quite weird. I wonder what Go thing you're invoking, and how...